# how to get java array list values inside javascript using java play framework

Tags: java, javascript, playframework

In my below given code i cant get java arraylist value inside javascript. I am new to java and play framework kindly guide me.

/* This is controller code */

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;
import play.data.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Application extends Controller {

     public static Result playGraph() {
        List<String> dashboardList = new ArrayList<String>();

        dashboardList.add("{First Value}");
        dashboardList.add("{Second Value}");


        return ok(playGraph.render(dashboardList));

}
}

/****** The above controller code is working fine the problem is only in template******

/******Template page playGraph.scala.html ************/


@(dashboardList:List[String])

@main("All Graph") {

Size:@dashboardList.size()
<br>
1st Value: @dashboardList.get(0); <!--This line prints First Value-->
<br>
2nd Value: @dashboardList.get(1);<!--This line prints Second Value-->

<script>
    alert(@dashboardList.size());//Alert shows 2
    alert(@dashboardList.get(0)); // ==> Not working
</script>

}
```

In this above code i cannot get @dashboardList.get(0) value in javascript but @dashboardList.size() is working.

Comment: If you do View Source in your browser, does it render as `alert(FirstValue)`? I think you just have a syntax error in your javascript because the string value is not in quotes - `alert("@dashboardList.get(0)");`

Comment: @Rhumborl make it an answer